# Smallest constant so that there are at least $n/\log_2{n}$ primes between $n$ and a constant multiple of $n$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

What is the smallest known $c$ so that for any $n\geq 2$ there are at least $n/\log_2{n}$ primes between $n$ and $cn$ (inclusive)?

The [prime number theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) seems to give an asymptotic result so I am not sure how to get a particular constant from it.

I am interested in answers that depend on well known conjectures as well as answers that are known to be correct.

Following a comment, the notation $\log_2{n}$ refers to taking the logarithm base $2$.

[Cross-posted from [math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1281888/the-number-of-primes-in-an-interval) where $c=13/6$ was suggested as a possibility.]

Comment: I can think of three interpretations for $\log_2 n$.  Which one do you have in mind?  Gerhard "Perhaps You Mean Base Two?" Paseman, 2015.05.15

Comment: @GerhardPaseman I mean log base two. For example $\log_2{8} = 3$. Does that reduce the number of options? (What were your three interpretations?)

Comment: Iterated log and a messed up version of $(\log n)^2$.  It would be nice for you to edit the question not only to clarify but to include some motivation.  Gerhard "If You Would, Pretty Please" Paseman, 2015.05.15

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Thank you. I am not sure if I should be embarrassed but my motivation is mathematical curiosity.

Comment: No reason to be embarrassed.  If it turns out that you had a thought like "Hey, maybe every even number $n$ can be a sum of two primes both at least $n/c$ in size by this easy counting argument...", you could reveal that and we could say "Yes, but ..." or "No, because ...", and answer that speculation for future readers.  If the motivation is "mature enough" (it doesn't have to be "technical enough"), it's OK for MathOverflow.  Just don't use too many words for it.  Gerhard "Like To Know Your Thoughts" Paseman, 2015.05.15

Comment: The prime number theorem has a sufficiently good error term to make this question an easy exercise. Voting to close as off-topic for the website.

Comment: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1255631807

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming I made no mistake, $c=11/5$ is the smallest such value.

Let $c=11/5$. Using Theorem 1 of [Rosser-Schoenfeld](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1255631807), we see easily that
$$\pi(cn)-\pi(n-1)\geq(\log 2)\frac{n}{\log n},\qquad n\geq 74,$$
where $\log$ is the natural logarithm as usual in analytic number theory. We can verify the same inequality for $2\leq n\leq 73$ by computer. Finally, for $n=5$ the above inequality means that there are at least $3$ primes in $[5,5c]$, whence $c\geq 11/5$ is necessary.

Comment: @eleanora: Actually, Rosser-Schoenfeld is the standard reference for such things. They wrote further papers, but this one is cited the most.

Comment: That is good to know. As you can tell, this is not my usual academic field.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, the suggestion given in the other thread is quite appropriate.  Use a lower bound from Dusart for $\pi(cn)$, and an upper bound for $\pi(n)$, and you want the difference between these bounds to be at least $n/\log_2 n$.  Using results from Dusart which apply for $n \gt $ three billion (primarily that $\pi(n) \leq (n/ \ln n)[1 + 1/ \ln n + 2.334 / (\ln n)^2]$ ), rewriting $1/ \ln n$ as $\epsilon$ and $1/ \ln cn$ as $\epsilon/(1 + \epsilon \ln c)$, after the dust settles one wants $c$ that satisfies

$$c \frac{1}{1 + \epsilon \ln c} [1 + \frac{\epsilon}{1 + \epsilon \ln c} 
+ \frac{2\epsilon^2}{(1+ \epsilon \ln c)^2}] > \ln 2 + 1 + \epsilon + 2.334 \epsilon^2,$$
where we have $\epsilon \lt 1/20$.  Thus, look for a $c$ that works for the first three billion $n$ (I haven't checked, but $c=13/6$ seems like a good candidate), and make sure that the above equation is satisfied for this $c$ and $\epsilon$ not too large (which it is for $c=13/6$, since the left hand side is at least 2 and the right hand side is less than 2.

Gerhard "Just A Matter Of Computation" Paseman, 2015.05.15

Comment: You can probably use older inequalities from Rosser/Schoenfeld which apply for all $n \gt 286$ to do a proof by hand.  Just check that $\epsilon$ is small enough to pull the result through.  Gerhard "Rewriting Terms Really Helps Here" Paseman, 2015.05.15

Comment: Indeed, such a computation has been outlined by GH from MO, who has even checked smaller values and found that $c=13/6$ does not quite cut it.  Gerhard "Missed It By That Much" Paseman, 2015.05.15